# PyGame - How to move many sprites at the same time?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, animation, pygame

Using PyGame, I created a sprite group for aliens in a space invaders style game.

My question is how can I get the aliens to move at the same time? Each instance of an Alien is stored in a list.

Comment: move every alien from list one-by-one with small "step". After that you start from the beginning. If you will repeat it in loop (mainloop) then it will look like all aliens move at the same time.

Comment: BTW: if alien will have function `update()` and you will keep in `grp = pygame.sprite.Group` then you need only `grp.update()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move every alien from list with small "step". After that you start from the beginning. If you will repeat it in loop (mainloop) then it will look like all aliens move at the same time.

```
# mainloop

while True:

   # events
   # ....

   # updates

   for aline in aliens_group:
       alien.rect.x += 1 # small move
       # or 
       alien.update() # function have to do small move

   # draws
   # ...
```

---

BTW: if alien will have function `update()` and you will keep aliens in  [pygame.sprite.Group](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) then you need only `group.update()`

```
class Alien:

     def update(self):
         self.rect.x += 1 # small move

# init

aliens_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

alien_1 = Alien()
alien_2 = Alien()

aliens_group.app(alien_1, alien_2)

# mainloop

while True:

   # events
   # ....

   # updates

   aliens_group.update() # function have to do small move

   # draws

   aliens_group.draw()
```

Comment: Nice work :) Your code is neat, and descriptive. The only thing I'd advice is the `map` function, the main point of my answer. Using iteration is much slower. In any case the `map` function is good practice :) Overall you code looks good :D

Comment: @CoolqB `pygame.sprite.Group()` is even better than `map`

Comment: Alright, let's time it, how long does your code take? I timed mine and it took... 0.0 seconds :P

I used cProfile. :)

Comment: @CoolqB I don't know how fast is `pygame.sprite.Group()` but it uses function from SDL library written in `C/C++` so it can be fast. But it better because it can be used with functions to detect collisions between sprites - so it has other advantages :)

Comment: ok, thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score -1):

OK assuming you have the positions of the aliens in the list you can use the `map` function:

```
aliens = [[0,0],[5,9],[5,2]] # Three aliens in list, these are their X,Y coords.

def move_alien_right(alien):
    alien[0] += 1
    return alien

aliens = list(map(move_alien_right,aliens))

print(aliens)
```

The `map` function is very fast, so if you have large groups of aliens it should work quite well.

Thanks :)

Comment: I have the rect values of each alien in a list. So would this still work?

Comment: A Pygame rect? If so absolutely I can edit my answer if that is the case :)

Comment: why the downvote?